# colored puts into text widget

Tags: tcl

When I want to output colorized string (red color) in terminal I use:

```
puts "\033\[00;31m Test String \033\[0m"
```

But when I print this string in text widget I get:

```
[00;31m Test String [0m
```

How to print the same colorized string in text widget?

Comment: tk widgets support a lot more functionality than is available in terminals, and uses a different "language" to express it.  Possible workaround? http://wiki.tcl.tk/1143

Comment: @TokenMacGuy You should propose that page as a solution; it looks like just the right thing.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: Well, I'm hoping that we will learn more about the problem Roman is trying to solve before I offer it as a solution, clearly he wants to see color, but why is he trying to use terminal escapes to show them?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I have tcl script that print Error notifications in red color to terminal. Now I'm trying to write GUI front-end that based on this script. So I want to continue to print Error notifications in the same color in text widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the question it is about applying formatting to content of text widget which has to do with Tk and not with escape sequences. This can be achieved through tags. Here is the code that would create a text widget, put two lines into it and highlight the second line with red.

```
set t [text .t -height 10 -width 40]
pack $t
$t insert end "text1\n"
$t insert end "text2\n"
$t tag add my_red 2.0 2.end
$t tag configure my_red -foreground red
```

I hope this helps if the question is just about formatting.

PN